# Swift access REST Web Service failed

Tags: ios, web-services, rest

Following this tutorial [tutorial](http://network-development.blogspot.sg/2014/06/access-rest-web-service-with-apples-new.html)

I'm able to invoke my web service which released base on springMVC, however the **connectionDidFinishLoading** does not seem to fire, and there isn't any error message either.

Here is my code.

```
import Foundation

class Requestor {

    var data: NSMutableData = NSMutableData();

    func connect() {
        var urlParth =  "http://localhost:8080/webservice/request/public/key";

        var url = NSURL(string: urlParth);
        var request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
        var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false);

        connection?.start();
    }

    //NSURLConnection Connection failed
    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        println("Failed with error:\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        println("didReceiveResponse")
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData conData: NSData!) {
        self.data.appendData(conData)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        println(self.data)
        println("did");
    }
}
```

here is my service code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/webservice")
public class PublicService extends Service {

    @RequestMapping("/request/public/key")
    public String requestPublicKey() {
        String result = String.format("{\"code\":\"%s\",\"publicKey\":\"%s\"}", "200", Base64.encodeBase64String(rasFactory.getPublicKeyInByte()));
        return result;
    }
}
```

I debugged for a quite long time by putting a break point in service, seems I can reach service, but after service returns the result, iOS side doesn't have any reaction.

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Thanks.

Comment: what error log you are getting in `didFailWithError` ?

Comment: error like '0x0000000...', and I found I didn't get a validate json string

Comment: this is what I get "{\"code\":\"200\",\"publicKey\":\"MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAh90CdoLWPGjgiTwQG066jf8Ky75LYed33IABtGlPmNWgP5WNybzP8jYRqn5ZBxP+K90pYp4TLtwzzjyKHfSK3pk/TtpDONBuGgxQjDzrZfl/7LpSkYGJtN3NbnMBI4/UhHPwXihgxaFGajngvwln8uH6OaXTEDcxHgmmVIJ3ehNEOhuYmoXylaytLoDyEHb0PQFuimja4FhhmXSy2ccDXs6VJSdN7hJsByu6T95E/cBwwXIxgYL6XrYwLH5GCU+lO5iVFR/OGFZx4Wu94CwUIyX2ZFMCRqEyL3ttxcvL+zCkRmpr9Te4LkjnZbU7Vymuf4zJ2YwMWA5/+W7iOgOcKwIDAQAB\"}"

Comment: That looks like a valid JSON response for a public key request...

Comment: I fixed this issue, trim first double quote and last double quote, replace "\" to "".